# What's the meaning of use PayPal\Api\object;

Tags: php, paypal

I was reviewing Paypal PHP SDK and something caught my attention.

In a [test class](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/tests/PayPal/Test/Api/PaymentTest.php#L5) there is this use statement:

```
use PayPal\Api\object;
```

I've searched for a class (or file) `object` within `Paypal\Api` but found nothing

What's the meaning of that use statement?
Is it a mistake? If it's not, in which cases should someone use a statement like that?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php

Comment: @zod I've read the link, do you mean that `object` should be a function in `Paypal\Api` namespace? I did not find any function called `object` in the codebase.

Comment: i also did a search and did not find. My doubt is , can we use "object" for class name or namespace . Isn't it reserved?  may be you can ask that question :-)

Comment: This is an unused import generated by our automated tools. I will go ahead and add a bug fix for it to not allow that.

Comment: Removed that as well as other unused imports : https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/commit/318d5a43c6eb74c7a91ba82e65bce2f92d565e29